# Android: Support external USB webcam

Tags: android, usb, webcam

I want to integrate 2 webcam(working as front and rear cam) in my app. I am not able to get any idea from where i can start. Any one tried to implement this type functionality or give me some basic approach so that i can work on it, that will be very helpful.

I would like to integrate this type of functionality - 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=infinitegra.trial.usbcamera

Google a little bit and redirected to the following site - 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html
http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk2.html